# Laravel symlink to separate repo and framework

Tags: laravel, symlink

I wrote a web app in Laravel. The repo doesn't store a whole Laravel installation - it only has `app` and `public` directories.

I'm trying to figure out a good solution to allow other devs to easily spin up a local version of my code for them to try/work on. Someone suggested that I set up a symlink between the cloned repo and my Laravel installation, which sounded like a good solution to me (allows them to push/pull from my repo without needing to copy files endlessly).

[image: File Structure]

However, when I set up the symlink, Laravel starts looking for its files (bootstrap, vendor, etc.) in the repo's directory, but they don't exist there, so I just get a blank screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why did you choose to not store all of the relevant app code? The base Laravel app code is still very much relevant to running a Laravel app. Maybe it'd be best to exclude your code out of a base Laravel install if you're trying to avoid a dependency on Laravel.

Comment: @Cryode Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems strange to store the whole framework when my app can just fit into a current Laravel installation.

Comment: The Laravel framework and the Laravel base/example application are two different things. That's why they are in two separate repositories on GitHub. The framework consists of agnostic components that can be used individually or together. The app is what puts them together and creates a web app using them. If your code is not dependent on the web app, then you can store your code separately. But if you're building a Laravel-specific application, you should include the base app's code in your repo.